# post on wall is not visible: using C#

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-wall

I am unable to post of Wall of a page. The code used to work few days back but now it is not working. My App made a post about 1.5 months back using the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

NameValueCollection PostData = new NameValueCollection();
PostData["access_token"] = ACCESSTOKEN;
PostData["name"] = "Test M";
PostData["description"] = "Test M";
PostData["message"] = "Test M";
PostData["link"] = "http://www.yettoknow.com";
byte[] response = wc.UploadValues("https://graph.facebook.com/" + PROFILEID + "/feed", "POST", PostData);
string res = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
```

I had tried different methods to make the post. I use to get a JSON response with an ID and I am able to view the message using Graph API for that ID but the post is not visible on my page's wall.

I am not sure if I need to change some settings related to privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log in facebook first in a tab then launch your web app in another tab.

Another lead: is your token still valid? DO you have an error return code on your post? Can you see the result in firebug or developer tools?

Comment: I am using a desktop application to post on wall. I had generated a new token few days back and it is still working. As I am able to make a post,because the response is OK and I am getting a JSON in response(from FB) which is providing a message ID to me. I am able to view message using Graph API but the message is not visible on page's wall.

Comment: It may take time to appear. You may also try to clear your cache and reload the facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your app settings to see if it is in **SANBOX MODE** or not,, if so disable the **sandbox** mode ( enabled by default when creating a new app ) and your posts should appear,, hope this helps.